# Sublime pressing enter in the middle of a bracket

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have moved from Netbeans to Sublime Text and this is just one of those little things that pull you away from your dream setup.

If you press enter in the middle of a brace, it does this:

```
$var = {
    | <-- cursor
}
```

But when you do it in a parenthesis or a bracket, it does this:

```
$var = (
    |)
```

and

```
$var = [
|]
```

I cannot find in the key bindings where the curly brace is set up. Any idea how I can just have these two work like the curly brace? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, I've found a way to do what you ask, but it's rather ugly and requires you to use `Tab` instead of `Enter`. If nobody will answer with a better way I'll post it.

Comment: Though I think you tried a ways to do it using an enter instead of a tab, it's a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what system you're on, but the key binding for this can be found on line 418 of the OSX keymap file.

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

When you press `enter`, it runs the macro file `res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro`. The `preceding_text` and `following_text` is a regex that defines when the command should be run.

By default, it is set to only run when the cursor is preceded by a curly-brace, and followed by a curly-brace. You can update the regex to include parentheses and brackets, and it will run when the cursor is between those as well.

Comment: Windows 8. It was there all along! I guess I missed it while cylcing through all the enter commands. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, answer posted by @Darrick Herwehe didn't work for me, here is what i have tried and working like a charm finally.

Add this to **User Keybinding**

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/Array Indent.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "array\\s*?\\($", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

Then touch & write contents to `Packages/User/Array Indent.sublime-macro`

```
[
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n\n"} },
    {"command": "left_delete", "args": null},
    {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false} },
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol", "extend": false} },
    {"command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": true} }
]
```